# Scalable naming convention for ordinal sizes?

Tags: design-system, design-tokens

Hopefully this is a good place for this question. I'm trying to put together concepts for a Design system, and I have a stumbling block on naming tokens.

Essentially, when I've got elements that are using ordinal values like xsmall, small, medium, large, xlarge... it isn't scalable.

I know I can go 'extra' on the end, i.e., 'extra-extra-extra-small' - but that's wordy, and it doesn't answer when I'm forced to add options in-between.
small-medium or small-medium-medium... don't really work.

How have others solved this problem for scalability? I found this article, but it only gives various options. https://speckyboy.com/naming-conventions-sizes-scalable-css/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use some alternative strategies to consider:

- **Use numeric values:** Instead of ordinal names, you can use numeric values to represent the sizes. For example, size1, size2, size3, and so on. This allows for easy insertion of new sizes without disrupting the existing naming structure. To make the relationship between the names and the actual sizes more intuitive, you can use a base value and increments that reflect the size difference, like size100, size200, size300, etc.
- **T-shirt sizes with extensions:** You can use T-shirt sizing (S, M, L, XL) with a numbered extension system to add new sizes in-between. For example, S1, S2, S3, M1, M2, M3, L1, L2, etc. This keeps the naming concise while still allowing for scalability.
- **Use a prefix with a numerical scale:** This approach combines the benefits of the two previous methods. You can use a prefix like 'size' followed by a number that represents the size on a numerical scale, e.g., size-1, size-2, size-3, and so on. If you need to add more sizes, you can simply extend the numerical scale.
- **Implement functional names:** Instead of using descriptive size names, focus on the function or purpose of the size, e.g., 'button-small', 'text-large', 'spacer-medium', etc. This can make it easier to manage sizes as your design system evolves, as you can add new functional size names when needed.
- **Use modular scale:** A modular scale is a sequence of numbers that relates to each other in a meaningful way, typically following a ratio. For example, a modular scale based on the golden ratio (1.618) could look like: 16, 26, 42, 68, 110, etc. You can use this sequence to define sizes for your elements and create a consistent visual hierarchy.